# Eclipse not opening on windows 8.1

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-8.1

So a couple of days ago i bought a new laptop, since my old one was way to old.
It came along with windows 8.1, which was the first time i used them since i was always with 7.

I downloaded the adt bundle that i used in my old pc, and when i attempted to open eclipse, i got the usual message about JRE/SDK missing, pretty logical, since i hadn't installed java.

So i went on and downloaded the latest java version (Java 8 update 60) and after i installed it eclipse refused to open at all. Absolutely nothing appears, not even the message that appeared before installing Java.
The fan starts working, like the program was running but absolutely nothing appears, it's not even on the processes on ctrl+alt+delete.

So are there any ideas on what might be causing this? It's a brand new laptop and eclipse flat out refuses to open. No error message, nothing, just eclipse not opening at all.

tried re-installing, running as admin, restarting, nothing works.

Comment: Did you install the public Oracle JRE8u60 or the Oracle JDK8u60?

Comment: Does your user Own and have Execute permissions to the entire directory where you unpacked Eclipse?

Comment: Oh damn, i had downloaded just java from oracle's site and i though JDK was included. Downloaded JDK and everything is ok, thanks a lot.